# Getting rid of the Filefield button when working with dropzone and flask-bootstrap forms

Tags: python, html, flask, dropzone.js

I am trying to display uploaded image files using `dropzone` and `flask`. Intentionally, I have used `flask-bootstrap` to help style my form. Everything works well, except for the appearance of the *Choose File* button inside the `dropzone` area. This is how it looks like:

[image]

It does not make sense to have the button in there, and I want to get rid of it. While working with `Filefield` from `flask_wtf.file`, I am having a hard time removing it.

This is how I render my form:

`forms.py`

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField
from wtforms import SubmitField


class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    file = FileField('Upload File', render_kw={"class": "dropzone"})
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

`index.html`

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-8">
       {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
   </div>
</div>
```

It would be so much easier to display the `dropzone` file upload form disregarding the use of `flask-bootstrap` to quickly create a simple form as follows:

`index.html`

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" class="dropzone">
           {{ form.hidden_tag() }} 
        </form>            
    </div>
</div>
```

And the result would be this:

[image]

I would like to maintain the use of `{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}` to create a form and not worry about *Choose File* button appearing in the middle of the `dropzone` upload file area. Is there a way to achieve this?